# Findstr giving access denied error

Tags: batch-file

Why is this findstr command giving me access denied?
It does with admin or standard run of cmd. and should be able to write to the folder it not a root or protected directory

```
findstr /v /c:"dataremove1" Users.twml > Users.tmp
```

inside Users.twml is

```
datakeep1
datakeep2
datakeep3
dataremove1
datakeep4
datakeep5
```

What i want is if dataremove1 is found in the file, "delete" it by taking it out and making a new file without it in. if there is another easier way with batch what would that be also.

@@@@ Edit Below @@@@

Chaging .tmp to .twmll the command works

```
findstr /v /c:"dataremove1" Users.twml > Users.twmll
```

Apparently .tmp is reserved for system level use only and not even admin can use it. changing to a different extension it works as it should.

Case closed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is caused by the redirect, but I don't know why you'd have problems if you're running as Administrator. What happens if you provide the full path to the output file and put it somewhere you have write permissions, like `"%userprofile%\Desktop\Users.tmp"`?

Comment: That worked it saved the  whole Users.twml file with the one line of dataremove1 gone. Hmm wonder why that would be, and i cant set hard paths since this is ran from a network drive, and users can assign different drive letters to their share.

Comment: in same directory im using findstr to read file contents of Users.twml to see if it contains name in first place, and using >> Users.twml echo %name2% to actually write to the Users.twml file. so i dont get why i cant read Users.twml and write Users.tmp to same location with new data.

Comment: got it! it just doesnt like the .tmp extension since its reserved for Windows system level use. i changed extension to .Twmll and it works perfectly

Comment: I use, _and always have used_, whatever file extension I feel like for temporary files, including `.tmp`. _(I select them specifically to use extensions for which no program is associated)_. I have never had an issue with `.tmp` being reserved for system use under any privilege level on any Windows OS.